# Android app shows decoded message from a Python socket server is null

Tags: python, android, sockets

I have used a socket to connect my android app to a python server. But I am not getting the text I passed from the server in the app.

The connection is made succesfully to the server and I see that A connection has been made successfully in the python terminal but the message is not getting decoded in android

Python Server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 1234
IP = socket.gethostname()

s.bind(('', port))
s.listen(10)


while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f'Connection from {address} has been established!')
    clientsocket.send(bytes("Welcome to the Server!", "utf-8"))
```

Android Client:

```java
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        TextView textView;
        Button button;
        String IP = "IPDEVICE";
        int port = 1234;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Connection c = new Connection();
                    c.execute(IP, String.valueOf(port));
                }
            });
        }
    
        class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    
            Socket s;
            DataInputStream d;
            String message;
            String IP1;
            int port1;
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                IP1 = strings[0];
                port1 = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]);
                try {
                    s = new Socket(IP1, port1);
                    d = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                    message = d.readUTF();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(message);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText("CONNECTION FAILED");
                        }
                    });
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The XML for this project has a text view `id=textView` and a button `id=button`

**EDIT**

In debug mode, the `message` is null. Why is that so?

Comment: `message = d.readUTF();` No you cannot use readUTF(). Instead use d.readLine() and let the server send a line by changing "Welcome to the Server!" to "Welcome to the Server!\n".

Comment: That worked thanks! Please make this an answer so that it'll be helpful if anyone else has the same doubt

Comment: Your comment will do.